# char type data in a double value in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a `char` type value which i need to put in a matrice of double , it is a mixed var type matrix ...

```
data=load('matric_wind.mat');
f=fieldnames(data);
ddd=f(20,1);
cc=numel(f)
FF=zeros(2,cc);
for i=1: cc 
  KKK =data.(f{i})  % get the table of *.mat 
  kk=(f{i})         %get the name of the table above
 digits = regexp( kk, '\d', 'match');
 result = [digits{:}]    %result is a char type value ,it is something like :'Windv_x_20070525_000000'

 FF(1,i)=KKK(49,156)    %FF(1,i) filled with double values
 FF(2,i)=result        
end
```

I receive `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`  error in line :`FF(2,i)=result` 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use str2num

Example:

```
x=str2num(x)
```

In your case:

```
FF(2,i) = str2num(result)
```

Type format long g first

```
>> format long g

>> '20070525000000'

ans =

20070525000000

>> str2num(ans)

ans =

     20070525000000
```

Comment: result is something like this :  `'20070525000000'`  but with what you suggest it change it to `2.oo71e+13`  i need the 20070525000000 part exactly as it is

Comment: @nazanin - Why don't you tell us **why** it's not working? What output are you expecting? The floating point representation of the number is the same number that you're seeking.

Comment: @rayryeng - i said it before what the problem is : i need exactly `20070525000000` because it is not a number it is a date in fact which i want to have it not in a scientific way with floating or sth.... in fact i need a matrice with different type of data in each column .... a column with double type var , anothercolumn char type var ,.....

Comment: @nazanin - MATLAB matrices are (by default) homogeneous.  You **cannot** have different columns with different data types, unless you use a `cell` array.  You should probably rethink the structure of your data before we proceed and help you any further.  I also don't see what the problem with scientific notation is.  If you're going to use the number **as is**, then it won't matter when you use it into functions that require such a large precision of numbers.  It's going to work either way.  If you want to **prettify** it, you have no choice but to use a string.  As such, try using `fprintf`.